# Why can't I add class on new dialog?

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I want to add a class in new Dialog. I'm using MFC Class Wizard, but I can't add a class. When I try to add a class, it shows:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: When old version of Visual Studio crashes, try a newer version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repair or re-install visual studio.